# Group By 3 columns (JobId, StartTime, EndTime) for continuous days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to group by the JobId, StartTime & EndTime only for continuous days. If a specific row doesn't form part of a range it should be discarded. The Id's should also pivot into a column per grouping.

| Id | Date | StartTime | EndTime | JobId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-23 | 08:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-08-24 | 08:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-08-24 | 12:30:00 | 14:30:00 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-08-24 | 15:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-08-25 | 08:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-08-25 | 12:30:00 | 14:30:00 | 2 |
| 7 | 2021-08-25 | 15:45:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 8 | 2021-08-26 | 08:30:00 | 09:30:00 | 1 |
| 9 | 2021-08-26 | 15:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 2021-08-26 | 10:30:00 | 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 11 | 2021-08-26 | 12:00:00 | 14:30:00 | 1 |
| 12 | 2021-08-27 | 08:30:00 | 09:30:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 2021-08-27 | 11:00:00 | 11:15:00 | 1 |
| 14 | 2021-08-27 | 11:30:00 | 14:30:00 | 1 |
| 15 | 2021-08-28 | 08:30:00 | 09:30:00 | 1 |

Using the above sample data you can see 3 groupings that can form such a continuous range.

Range 1 consists of Id's, 1,2 & 5 - 2021-08-23 to 2021-08-25, 08:30:00 to 19:00:00

Range 2 consists of Id's 3 & 6 - 2021-08-24 to 2021-08-25, 12:30:00 to 14:30:00

Range 3 consists of Id's 8, 12 & 15 - 2021-08-26 to 2021-08-28, 08:30:00 to 09:30:00

The end result should be:

| JobId | StartDate | EndDate | StartTime | EndTime | Ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-23 | 2021-08-25 | 08:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 1,2,5 |
| 2 | 2021-08-24 | 2021-08-25 | 12:30:00 | 14:30:00 | 3,6 |
| 1 | 2021-08-26 | 2021-08-28 | 08:30:00 | 09:30:00 | 8,12,15 |

MySQL 8.0.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `` JobId, `Date`, StartTime, EndTime `` is unique you may use:

```sql
SELECT JobId,
       MIN(`Date`) StartDate,
       MAX(`Date`) EndDate,
       StartTime,
       EndTime,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Id) Ids
FROM test
GROUP BY JobId,
         StartTime,
         EndTime
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   AND DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) = COUNT(*) - 1
ORDER BY StartDate, StartTime
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fce8590f72ac1d50cd9e89add3ed01e7